# Reverse bits the obvious way

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I saw the link http://pvtridvs.net/pool/bithacks.html#BitReverseObvious and posted the code here:

```
unsigned int v;         // reverse the bits in this
unsigned int t = v;     // t will have the reversed bits of v
int i;

for (i = sizeof(v) * 8 - 1; i; i--)
{
  t <<= 1;
  v >>= 1;
  t |= v & 1;
}
```

Would someone explain a little bit why this look-simple algorithm works? I tested on paper some of the simplest examples, say 4-bit 0011 etc, it works, but I simply do not understand why these 3 lines of shift and bit-wise op can achieve it.

Comment: The URL has "The first method takes about 18 operations ..." which I disagree with.  The first method does 6 operations per iteration and 32 iterations for other 180 operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shifts bits "out" of the low positions of `v` and "in" to the low positions of `t`.  Think of the variables as stacks of bits.  You're popping bits from `v` and pushing them into `t`.  Popping from one list and pushing onto another initially empty list is a simple way to reverse any list.  The intialization just performs the initial "push" of the lowest order bit onto the result.  This trick saves one pup and push (i.e. a right and left shift).  E.g. for a byte, only 7 more pop-pushes are needed.

Comment: "Note the intialization of t is useless." Not true — it's essential, in order to get the least-significant-bit of `v`.

Answer (score 0):

Each round `t` is shifted one position up, `v` is shifted one position down; and the currently last but of `v` is placed at the end of `t`.